# similar function like RTD() of ms-excel to insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, storing-data, rtd

I am currently fetching real time data which i get in my excel sheet using

```
=rtd(some parameters)
```

the way `RTD` function evaluates those parameters and gives some value, is there a similar function in php/some other that can do the same, passing the above parameters.

thank you...

Comment: Write a PHP script that you then run as a scheduled `cron` task... but the question is way too broad to be answered.

Comment: What's the data source?

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry could not express well enough.

Comment: @AlessandroNiciforo my data source is the stock exchange changing rates.